# How to Clip out a region of IDXGISurface?

Tags: directx, direct2d, direct3d11, dxgi

I am a beginner so my question might sound silly.
I have a IDXGISurface which holds some data/image. I wish to crop certain rectangle areas out of it and store it into same IDXGISurface or another similar surface. I believe Direct2D provides a way to do it through layers. 
Any guidance on this (preferable step by step) would be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you give some code snippets that you have tried or working already?

Comment: I am trying to do as follows:
1. D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &Direct2D); //create D2 factory
2. Direct2D->CreateDevice(DxgiDevice, &Direct2DDevice);//create d2 device.  3.Direct2DDevice->CreateDeviceContext(D2D1_DEVICE_CONTEXT_OPTIONS_NONE, &Screen); // create d2 device context
4. Screen->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(dxgiBackBuffer, &bitmapProperties, &Direct2DBitmap);//create bitmap from IDXGISurface
5. Screen->PushLayer(...... //Direct 2D Drawing. 

Now will this result in drawing in dxgiBackbuffer mentioned in step 4. Awaiting your reply

Comment: It might be a good idea to add the code in your question, instead in form of a comment.